# Azure AKS App Gateway Ingress and Istio Ingress Gateway

Tags: azure, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, istio, azure-aks

Is anyone tried to use this bundle? Main question if it's really make sense as long main advantage of App Gateway as K8S Ingress Controller is ability to connect directly to pods, avoiding NodePort schema.
And in case of Istio Ingress Gateway we still have additional hop to pods, so L3 Azure ILB should be also fine?

Comment: this doesnt make nay sense. App Gateway is L7, load balancer is L4. App gateway (or load balancer) cannot connect directly to pods, its associated to hosts. And what is the actual question?

Comment: @4c74356b41 There is an app gateway ingress controller (AGIC): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/ingress-controller-overview. I am using it on a project and it works great. For this project we needed to use app gateway so using AGIC we don't need to have another load balancer. I would say if you need app gateway on top of your cluster using AGIC make sense but really depends on your use case.

Comment: I know what a Application Gateway ingress controller is, but its not L3. other things to consider - lack of features of Application Gateway compared to Istio Gateway. Having to justify paying for an Application Gateway, etc

Comment: @4c74356b41 yes, it could connect directly to pods because azure CNI pods has IP address directly in vnet, the question is it make sense to combine App Gateway and istio

Comment: no, it doesn't. because application gateway is strictly inferior to istio ingress gateway

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that the main advantage of `AGIC` is not necessarily the ability to connect directly to pods but to be able to use the `WAF` functionality of the Application Gateway and have `Microsoft` support, which is sometime needed for big corpo. If you are not planning to use the `WAF` functionality of the Application Gateway, it don't really make sense to use `AGIC` instead of a `L4` load balancer in front of the `Istio Ingress Gateway`.

Comment: If the "ability to connect directly to pods" isn't an advantage, I don't know what is. WAF can be easily replaceable at FrontDoor or an internal API GW but the ability to talk to pods directly using their private IPs clearly shows a performance advantage here.